# Heroku unable to access jetty-runner jar file

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku, jetty

I'm deploying a Spring MVC app to Heroku using jetty-runner.jar, but I get an error in the deployment.
The Heroku logs only show:

```
Error: unable to access jarfile target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar
State changed from starting to crashed
Process exited with status 1
```

However, the app is working correctly if I run it locally using either:

```
heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
```

or

```
java -jar target\dependency\jetty-runner.jar target\*.war
```

The file under "target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar" is created correctly in my computer when running the "mvn package" command.

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

My pom.xml file and project code are located in:
https://github.com/gfigueroa/nlp-tools-spring-heroku

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS**

I ran the command `heroku run ls target` after deploying and it only shows the `.war` file. The `dependency` folder was not created when deploying, even though it was when I packaged my project locally.

Comment: is the issue resolved? Just wanted to check since I replaced webapp-runner.jar with jetty runner and was able to successfully deploy to heroku.

Comment: What is the output of running `heroku run ls target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar`?

Comment: @localhost999 Not resolved yet.
@codefinger This is what I get: 
`ls: cannot access targetdependencyjetty-runner.jar: No such file`...for some reason it's removing the backslashes. (running on Windows by the way).

Comment: @localhost999 I tried it with webapp-runner.jar and it gives me the same error: `Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar` in the Heroku logs after deploying.

Comment: @codefinger I ran `heroku run ls target` and it only shows the `.war` file. The `dependency` folder and other folders are not created on the Heroku repository as they are locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `maven-clean-plugin` is deleting the `jar` file in `dependency` directory and other required directories when you try to build  your app on `Heroku`.

You can either remove the `maven-clean-plugin` in the `pom.xml` or you can modify it.

Best option is to remove the plugin below in pom.xml

```
              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.5</version>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>clean-jar-artifacts</id>
                      <phase>install</phase>
                      <goals><goal>clean</goal></goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                        <filesets>
                          <fileset>
                              <directory>target</directory>
                              <excludes>
                                <exclude>*.war</exclude>
                              </excludes>
                          </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Or you can exclude the `dependency/*.jar` from deleting by simply adding the `<exclude>..</exclude>` tags as specified below. But this option might delete other required folders which are necessary for deploying the app successfully. So I would not recommend this.

```
    <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>clean-jar-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>clean</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                                <filesets>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <directory>target</directory>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>*.war</exclude>
                                            <exclude>dependency/*.jar</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </filesets>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Look at this [page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html) for more information.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! I am executing the maven-clean-plugin to make my slug-size in Heroku smaller, since most (if not all) of the code in the target directory is redundant with that inside the .war file.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem , until I add into pom.xml file with latest jetty-runner (org.eclipse.jetty)

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                              <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                              <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                              <version>9.4.4.v20170414</version>
                       <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Procfile contains only: 
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war